# How to set itemWidth in Buefy carousel component?

Tags: vue.js, buefy, gridsome

I am using `Buefy Carousel List` from `https://buefy.org/documentation/carousel#carousel-list` in a `Gridsome` single file component. I need to change the width of the slides from the default (476.25) to the `width` of my own images (176).

In `Vue dev` tools, I can manually override the data prop `itmeWidth`. This displays correctly and Vue dev tools shows that the computed prop has been changed to `itemStyle: "width: 176px;"`

How do I code the new width into the component? I have tried via styling `(.carousel-slide width: 176px)`, data props `(itemWidth: 176)` and computed props `(itemStyle: "width: 176px;")`. All are ignored and the default width is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No API option/support for **custom width slide** set by **CSS** (**Example:** On swiper `slidesPerView: auto` is API option for this idea - see [swiper demos](https://swiperjs.com/demos/)).

https://buefy.org/documentation/carousel/#api-view

For `carousel list` the **width** added by Javascript (Inline CSS) - Example:

[image]

Anyway, `!important;` will change the width (Output: broken layout).

```
.carousel-item{
  width: 176px!important;
}
```

#### items-to-show

One more idea/option for custom width: Use `items-to-show` and decimal (`3.2` for example).

[image]

Comment: items-to-show did it in Vue Gridsome, thank you. I put :items-to-show="slidesPerView" in the v-bind statements, and slidesPerView: 11 in the data statements.

Comment: Great :) please mark as anwer to "close" this topic.